Identify temporary layer when choosing parameter
When working I tend to create a lot of temporary layers that I don't bother to name but in which order are they presented when choosing parameter?
Chronological or the same order as in your project or something else?
In ArcView3.2 it was automatically added a number like Union1 + Union2 is that possible in Qgis?


You can somehow get close from what you ask by selecting Run as Batch in your Union function (same for any Vector tool function).
Add as many processing options you wish.
Set the output layer name thanks to the Calculate by Expression option in the right most column.
Set this to something like:
concat('/Users/username/Desktop/temporary ', @Parameter1,'-',@Parameter1,'.gpkg' )
for instance if you have two parameters to consider.
Tick the `Load layers on completion'
After processing, the layers will be listed with the parametric name you have set: temporary parameter1 - parameter2 for each layer.
This is an example, with a line and different buffer distances:

The difference with your specific resuest is that these are not temporary layers, but nothing prevents you from deleting thé files afterwards.
Otherwise if you really want temporary layers, I fear you need to manually edit the name of each temporary layer every time you generate one
